# SharePoint Spreadsheet Not Updating Properly

Tags: excel, sharepoint, synchronization, power-automate

I have an Excel spreadsheet connected to a Microsoft Form using Power Automate. When the form is submitted, the answers feed directly into the spreadsheet.

When the form is submitted, the desktop version of the spreadsheet updates, as does the web version if I click on the link from OneDrive. HOWEVER, the version I have uploaded to SharePoint does not update. I've checked the flow on Power Automate and all is well. I tried to Delete the Cache in the spreadsheet as advised by a number of help sites, but that doesn't update the SharePoint version.

Does anyone know how to fix this so that the link on SharePoint updates just like the other versions of the same document? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your Form results are fed to an Excel file in your personal OneDrive by Power Automate.
You can open this file in the browser and in the desktop Excel. It is literally the same data, kept up to date by the Power Automate flow.
However, if you uploaded this to SharePoint it is merely a copy, a snapshot of the OneDrive document at the time of uploading. The flow will not update it.
What you could do:

1. Re-configure the flow to update the SharePoint file, then use the Sync functionality to keep a synced copy in your OneDrive.
2. Add another flow step to also update the SharePoint file (and keep updating the OneDrive file, the two will be independent).
3. Also, you could use Power Query in Excel to create a refreshable table pulling information from the source you update with the Power Automate flow.

Comment: Flow solved it! Thanks so much.